# How not to update the ddl schema in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, schema, ddl

I try to run an application with spring batch and scheduler. I see that the ddl schema is always updated and I don't want to change my ddl schema.

I try this in my application.properties file :

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate|none
```

But it doesn't resolve my problem.

Here are my differents files :

*application.properties*

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/ussd_service
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

#Hibernate Configuration:
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true

#DB initialization
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=validate
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

And my class where I define my datasource

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EntityScan("com.package.myentity")
@ComponentScan(basePackages   = {"com.package.batch.",
                                 "com.package.repository"})
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class BatchSmsJobConfig {

  @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
  private String databaseDriver;
  @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
  private String databaseUrl;
  @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
  private String databaseUsername;
  @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
  private String databasePassword;

  @Bean
  public ItemReader<Souscription> reader() throws Exception {
    java.util.Date now = new java.util.Date();
    java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(now.getTime());
    String jpqlQuery = "select u from Users u";

    JpaPagingItemReader<Souscription> reader = new JpaPagingItemReader<Souscription>();
    reader.setQueryString(jpqlQuery);
    reader.setParameterValues(Collections.<String, Object>singletonMap("date", date));
    reader.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    //reader.setPageSize(3);
    reader.afterPropertiesSet();
    reader.setSaveState(true);

    return reader;
  }

  @Bean
  public SouscriptionItemProcessor processor() {
    System.out.println("Processing!");
    return new SouscriptionItemProcessor();
  }


  @Bean
  public ItemWriter<Sms> writer() {
    System.out.println("Writing info into DB!");
    JpaItemWriter writer = new JpaItemWriter<Sms>();
    writer.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());

    return writer;
  }

  //@Bean
  //public JobExecutionListener listener() {
  //  return new JobCompletionNotificationListener(jdbcTemplate);
  //}

  @Bean
  public Job sendSMStoSubscribersJob(JobBuilderFactory jobs, Step s1) {

    return jobs.get("import")
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .flow(s1)
        .end()
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, ItemReader<Souscription> reader,
                    ItemWriter<Sms> writer, SouscriptionItemProcessor processor) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
        .<Souscription, Sms>chunk(1)
        .reader(reader)
        .processor(processor)
        .writer(writer)
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(databaseDriver);
    dataSource.setUrl(databaseUrl);
    dataSource.setUsername(databaseUsername);
    dataSource.setPassword(databasePassword);
    return dataSource;
  }

  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    lef.setPackagesToScan("com.mobilproafrica.batch.sms");
    lef.setDataSource(dataSource());
    lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
    lef.setJpaProperties(new Properties());
    return lef;
  }

  @Bean
  public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.POSTGRESQL);
    jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
    jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

    jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
    return jpaVendorAdapter;
  }
}
```

I see in the console logs like :

> org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000388: Unsuccessful:
>   alter table tarif add constraint FK_lub9g2gwhub3a7pc7u67vp3cr foreign
>   key (forfait_id) references forfait

Can somebody help me on this error?

Comment: Only adding a property won't work, if you don't use that property. If you are using Spring Boot that is even the wrong property.

Comment: Please provide some information on how you configure hibernate. Do you use springboot, or hibernate.cfg.xml, or you define your own "org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean" with datasource?

Comment: @gmaslowski, yes I am using springboot. And I think the only file Ihave to configureis application.properties

Answer (score 2):

Set

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

in application.properties.

Comment: OK I found the solution. I just had to set the generte DDL to false in my bean jpavendorAdapter like that : jpavendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false)

Comment: @TheGuide That's why I've asked you how do you configure your datasource.. and your answer saying that you're only configuration was application.properties (notice that code is configuration too!) was misleading. Good that you have figured it out.